# FATAL EXCEPTION в приложении

Tags: android

При очередной компиляции приложения, оно начило выбивать ошибку(Приложение остановлено). Даже после того, как я комментировал все в MainActivity(осталось только `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`) все равно ошибка

```
08-20 16:19:26.374 16269-16269/org.antonin.newprogect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.antonin.newprogect, PID: 16269
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class Button
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at org.antonin.newprogect.Fragment.Follows.onCreateView(Follows.java:41)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_clear_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020015
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:58)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at org.antonin.newprogect.Fragment.Follows.onCreateView(Follows.java:41) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554) 
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623) 
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:58) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067) 
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at org.antonin.newprogect.Fragment.Follows.onCreateView(Follows.java:41) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: возможно глюк студии, сделайте clean project - затем rebuild.

Comment: Спосибо, помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно глюк студии, сделайте clean project - затем rebuild.